# How handle URL Encoded Characters in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How to handle URL Encoded Characters like colon (`%3A`) in JSoup connect function?

Answer (score 1):

What you could basically do is encode the URL before you use it in JSOUP. 
I believe what you are trying to do here is pass some parameters to the host in the URL itself.

To encode the URL, use the below code:

```
String url = "https://google.com?q=i wish to search something";
String encodeURL=URLEncoder.encode( url, "UTF8" );
```

Here's the answer to your comment:

```
package com.abk;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
public class JsoupTest{  
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URLDecoder.decode("https://siccode.com/en/business-list/sic%3A2211%22","UTF8")).get();  
                String title = doc.title();  
                System.out.println("title is: " + title);  
    }  
}
```

This should work like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. My real problem is i have a url which has (%3A) a colon character like below

String url = "https://siccode.com/en/business-list/sic%3A2211"

When I pass this url into 

 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).validateTLSCertificates(false).get();

It did not show me page html

Comment: @MuhammadNaeemShahzad Did it help?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Showing this exception I even add .validateTLSCertificates(false)

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: I connected the same URL without any trouble. There is no need for validateTLSCertificate thing

Comment: @MuhammadNaeemShahzad I just made a small correction. Use UTF8 without a dash and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String decodedString1 = URLDecoder.decode("siccode.com/en/business-list/sic%3A2211", "UTF-8");
```

as its url encoded you need to decode it before using.

> Sample for JS.

```js
var str = decodeURIComponent("siccode.com/en/business-list/sic%3A2211");

console.log(str);
```